# About text function in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Why is this wrong？
    x=1:10;
    y=1:10;
    plot(x,y);
    text(1,1,'a');
How to use text function in MATLAB? I always get a exceed dimension error. Anyone could help me?

Comment: Did you define a variable `text`? What is the output of `who text`?

Answer (score 0):

Is't wrong.

You write the 'a' in the point x = 1 and y = 1.

Try with

```
x=1:10; y=1:10; plot(x,y); text(5,7,'hello');
```